# Maven remote archetype from Nexus offers all snapshots instead of only the last one

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus, maven-archetype

I have generated a Maven archetype which has been uploaded to a Nexus repository (`mvn deploy`). This archetype is still a SNAPSHOT.

When I try to generate a project `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -U` I am offered every uploaded SNAPSHOT, when I am only interested in the last one:

```
1: 1.0.0-20181218.103104-1
2: 1.0.0-20181218.104810-2
```

Instead I would like to have:

```
1: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Is there some way to configure this behaviour? If the number of SNAPSHOTS grow it would be unmanageable.

My remote archetype-catalog.xml file has an entry per SNAPSHOT-TIMESTAMP...

Comment: What version of NXRM are you on?

Comment: Nexus version is OSS 3.14.0-04